# Addto* - deleteobject - addto* will throw error

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

Basically I insert a row, delete that row, then insert a new row with the same key again.  It will throw an exception on the last line savechanges:  "AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges." I confirmed the deleteobject call works.  How do I let the objectstatemanager know that the record is gone and can be reinserted?

```
        Maps _newMaps = new Maps();

        _newMaps.map_page = "BLA";
        _newMaps.descr = "BLA test";
        opendb.AddToMaps(_newMaps);

        opendb.SaveChanges(true);


        foreach (var mapsrec in opendb.Maps)
        {
            opendb.DeleteObject(mapsrec);
        }
        opendb.SaveChanges(true);

        Maps _sameMaps = new Maps();

        _sameMaps.map_page = "BLA";
        _sameMaps.descr = "BLA test";
        opendb.AddToMaps(_sameMaps);

        opendb.SaveChanges(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Further research shows that you have to Detach() the object (record) you added to the state manager for it to truly forget about it even after doing a DeleteObject().  So code that would let you add a rec, delete it, add record with same keys would look like:

```
    Maps _newMaps = new Maps();

    _newMaps.map_page = "BLA";
    _newMaps.descr = "BLA test";
    opendb.AddToMaps(_newMaps);

    opendb.SaveChanges(true);


    foreach (var mapsrec in opendb.Maps)
    {
        opendb.DeleteObject(mapsrec);
        opendb.Detach(_newMapt);
        opendb.SaveChanges(true);
    }


    Maps _sameMaps = new Maps();

    _sameMaps.map_page = "BLA";
    _sameMaps.descr = "BLA test";
    opendb.AddToMaps(_sameMaps);

    opendb.SaveChanges(true);
```